# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError JPanel

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, stack-overflow

I'm getting this error when I try to run program that creates a Panel inside a Frame

I didn't paste some parts of code like variable declaration because I didn't have much space!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
        at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults$TextAndMnemonicHashMap.get(UIDefaults.java:1244)
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getFromResourceBundle(UIDefaults.java:288)
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.get(UIDefaults.java:162)
        at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.get(MultiUIDefaults.java:64)
        at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:753)
        at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1016)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
        at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
```

### LoginWindow.java:

Creates the main panel, divided into sub panels which contain labels,textfields and button

```
public class LoginWindow extends JPanel {

    public LoginWindow() {

        LoginWindow p1 = new LoginWindow();
        LoginWindow p2 = new LoginWindow();
        LoginWindow p3 = new LoginWindow();
        LoginWindow p4 = new LoginWindow();
        LoginWindow p5 = new LoginWindow();
        LoginWindow p0 = new LoginWindow();

        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 1, 1));
        p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 1, 1));
        p5.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        p0.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        password = new JPasswordField();
        email = new JTextField();
        label_password = new JLabel("Password");
        label_email = new JLabel("Email");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(p0,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        sign_in = new JLabel("Sign in");
        sign_in.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        sign_in.setForeground(Color.red);
        p0.add(sign_in,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        p1.add(p3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p1.add(p4, BorderLayout.NORTH);     

        p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray, 1, true));

        p4.add(label_email);
        p4.add(email);

        p3.add(label_password);
        p3.add(password);

        button = new Button("Create Account");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 30));
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(blank.equals(password.getPassword().toString()) || blank.equals(email.getText())){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email or password missing !");
                }else {
                    DataBase db = new DataBase();
                    db.insertData(password.getPassword().toString(), email.getText());
                }
            }
        });

        p5.add(button);
        p2.add(p5,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

### window.java:

Creates an object from window class, and adds the created panel to the tabbed pane, all inside the main frame

```
public class window extends JFrame {

    public window() {
        super("Window");
        setSize(300,230);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //setResizable(false);
        setLocation(600, 100);

        JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
        LoginWindow panel = new LoginWindow();
        tabPane.addTab("Sign in",panel );

        add(tabPane);
        //pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        window frame = new window();
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution: don't user recursion unnecessarily.

Comment: @Psychosis404 Can you give us the full code.. some definitions are missing. Also what are you trying to make exactly? 6 different login windows? 1 page with 6 repeating login sections? ... bit confused.

Comment: Problem solved, i just had to add another constructor

Answer (score 2):

```
public class LoginWindow extends JPanel {

     public LoginWindow() {

                LoginWindow p1 = new LoginWindow();
```

You are trying to instantiate LoginWindow inside the constructor of LoginWindow. And hence the recursion.

Probably you need to have another class/panel and use it here ?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating 6 new LoginWindow inside the constructor for LoginWindow.
This results in an infinite loop.

This loop goes on and on until there is a stackoverflow:

```
public LoginWindow() {

            LoginWindow p1 = new LoginWindow();
            LoginWindow p2 = new LoginWindow();
            LoginWindow p3 = new LoginWindow();
            LoginWindow p4 = new LoginWindow();
            LoginWindow p5 = new LoginWindow();
            LoginWindow p0 = new LoginWindow();
```

Try the following that is based on your code:

All you have to do is add the appropriate layouting in order to position your elements correctly:

```
class LoginWindow extends JFrame{


    public LoginWindow() {
        JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
        JTextField email = new JTextField();
        JLabel label_password = new JLabel("Password");
        JLabel label_email = new JLabel("Email");

        JLabel sign_in = new JLabel("Sign in");
        sign_in.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        sign_in.setForeground(Color.red);

        Button button = new Button("Create Account");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 30));
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        String blank = "";

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(blank.equals(password.getPassword().toString()) || blank.equals(email.getText())){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email or password missing !");
                }else {

                }
            }
        });


        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300,230);
        setLocation(600, 100);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(label_email);
        email.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
        panel.add(email);

        panel.add(label_password);
        password.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
        panel.add(password);


        panel.add(button);

        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

}
```

And to run:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginWindow frame = new LoginWindow();    
   }
```

Comment: What's the alternative ??

Comment: @Psychosis404 Really depends on what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Psychosis404 It seems to be you want to create 6 different login panels and place them all on the same window? Or am I wrong? Or do you want 6 different windows to pop up?

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos I want to create a main panel that holds other panels which contain button,textfields and labels, all in a window

Answer (score -1):

I added a new constructor:

```
public LoginWindow(LayoutManager l) {
    //Constructor for the main panel
}

public LoginWindow() {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    LoginWindow p1 = new LoginWindow(new BorderLayout());
    LoginWindow p2 = new LoginWindow(new BorderLayout());
    LoginWindow p3 = new LoginWindow(new GridLayout(2, 1, 1, 1));
    LoginWindow p4 = new LoginWindow(new GridLayout(2, 1, 1, 1));
    LoginWindow p5 = new LoginWindow(new GridBagLayout());
    LoginWindow p0 = new LoginWindow(new BorderLayout());

...
}
```

And when you create the main panel in window.java:

```
LoginWindow panel = new LoginWindow();
```

Comment: Why are you creating the same object within the same class? Why such design approach?